# how to add Ads on Splash Screen for Windows Phone

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am trying to add  a Advertisement on a splash screen.
Basically what it want to do is display an Advertisement on start up of an application 
for windows phone 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Windows Phone 8 is quite faster than its predecessor, default project templates come without splash screen as it is no longer necessary. But if you still insist, you can create it by following this document: [How to create a splash screen for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769511%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

But be aware that it might load too fast for user to notice it.

Comment: i dont need a splash screen instead i want to display an advertisement  in place of splash screen.

Comment: i want to display an ads on application start up and then load to its main page

Comment: Then make the first page user sees when (s)he opens the app is the page with the ad on it

Comment: how to create first page and load it first and then the mainpage

Comment: Do you know how to a) create new pages, b) change application's starting page, c) navigating from one page to another?

Answer (score 0):

The splashscreen on windows phone (created by setting a splashscreenimage.jpg) file is static. If you insist on adding an ad to a splashscreen, you'll need to create a custom popup overlaying the mainpage.

An example - http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Custom_splash_screen_with_progress_bar_for_Windows_Phone_applications

Comment: i want to display an ads on application start up and then load to its main page

Comment: Yes, and the link i provided above gives an example of how to create an interactive splash screen. You'll need yo modify the code to show an ad, but that's your starting point.